# How to change Adobe Illustrator CC's pixel to inch ratio?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, dpi, ppi

We all know today the devices have different ppi. Traditionally a pixel is a point, which is 1/72 an inch. But today, iPhones have 326 pixel per inch why the point should remain the same for typography practice (12 pt is readable on a desktop monitor but would be too small for iPhone, instead we need 54 to 55 pt on the art board).

This is bad because if I design for multiple devices, I have to change the typography across the art-boards to match similar visual outcomes. Photoshop has provided solution to this issue a long time ago. I wonder if there is some hack we can do to accomplish the same solution in Illustrator.

Comment: Illustrator artwork (other than raster effects) is resolution independent though.

Comment: To be pedantic, traditionally, a pixel is a dimensionless unit. If you think for a moment about your (our) predicament, you will quickly realize that the different density screens all have different dimensions **in inches**, this leaves you with only one possible fixed unit: the dot.

Comment: Okay, sure, how do I user 326 pixels per inch while using 72 points per inch?

Answer (score 4):

You can always design in absolute pixels since your monitor and your devices will never have the same pixel density. For example, you could design everything in xhdpi and therefore maintain the same size throughout. Googles holo templates for example work that way too (but in mdpi). The only difference that you'll experience is that your desktop won't show it in the precise density. But since that's impossible anyway I wouldn't worry about it. And you need to test your designs on a device anyway. So set up your artboards to match the testing device and you will always have a correct preview on it.

Have a look at googles samle files: https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't worry about it. iphone and other high pixel density screens have been doing a fine job at keeping resolutions scaled correctly. as far as designing goes, i'd only be concerned with exporting the artwork at the desired ppi. if you want "retina-ready" here is a blog post that hits the gist of it, and several links to tuts and other resources.

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/why-should-you-become-retina-ready/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can change pixel to inch in Adobe Illustrator, but when I need to convert pixels to inches in Photoshop I'm [using this web tool to convert inches to pixels](http://www.ninjaunits.com/convert-inches-pixels/), then create a new file with the obtained dimensions.

Comment: Hi Andreea, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!